# Image is not showing up.Is it a path problem?

Tags: c#, asp.net, path

.aspx

```
                <tr>
                    <th><asp:Label runat="server" ID="_imageName" Text="이미지"></asp:Label></th>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Image ID="_image" runat="server" Height="190px" Width="360px" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

.aspx.cs

```
_image.ImageUrl = "D:\SVN\Project\ImageFiles\10238\imagetest2.jpg";
```

Image is not showing up.

Is it a path problem? 
The image file is definitely in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
_image.ImageUrl = "~/ImagesFiles/10238/imagetest2.jpg";
```

Or directly in your HTML :

```
<td>
    <asp:Image ID="_image" runat="server" Height="190px" Width="360px" ImageUrl="~/ImagesFiles/10238/imagetest2.jpg" />
</td>
```

see documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.image.imageurl?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

The client page isn't accessing the file. It's just setting the file's path to the HTML output for the client (web browser) to access it. Resulting in this:

```
<img src = "D:\SVN\Project\ImageFiles\10238\imagetest2.jpg" />
```

Since the user doesn't have access to that file(img) (because it is available for localhost, you must serve this file(img)), the img tag won't work.